# Wait for network idle after click

Tags: playwright, playwright-java

I'm looking for a method that would allow me to wait for the network idle after clicking a button or some action.
there is a way to wait for the network idle after clicking?
`page.locator("text=Click").click() //some method that wait network is idle after clicking the button`

I tried waitForLoadState works only if there is navigation.
waitForResponse works on specific requests but it's not good for me.

Comment: Just to clarify, when you click the button, the page remains on the same URL, no reload of the url is performed, and the click loads something in dynamically?

Comment: Yes you right fetch data on same URL, "client side rendering" .

Answer (score 5):

There is a playwright library for network idle wait.

```
await page.waitForLoadState('networkidle')
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: This is addressed in the question: `waitForLoadState` is usable only while the page is loading, not after a button click.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `waitForResponse` if you know what particular network communication you're initiating with the button click and thus know what URLs you can use to monitor the requests/responses of to see if the communication has finished yet.

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response

For example:

```js
// Click the *Delete* button
await page.getByText('Delete').click();

// Wait for the `api/items/delete` endpoint to be called
await page.waitForResponse(/\/api\/items\/delete/);
```

Unfortunately this won't cover the scenario of waiting after all network activity settles after the button click.

Answer (score 1):

As your use case is to click a link which dynamically loads in other DOM Elements, you could possibly try using [.waitForSelector()](https://playwright.dev/java/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector).

```
page.locator("text=Click").click()
page.waitForSelector('selector for what you are waiting for here')
```

Also pass options to waitForSelector to wait for it being attached and / or visible and setTimeout appropriately.

I was going to suggest using assertion polling but I don't believe the Java version of playwright has that yet.

Answer (score 0):

I think combining wait for response with some *visible UI change* after fetch request will help:

```
await button.click() 
await page.waitForResponse(res => res.status() === 200) 

const newText = await page.getByRole('paragraph') 
const newImage = await page.getByRole('img')
 
await expect(newText).not.toEqual(prevText) 
await expect(newImage).not.toEqual(prevImage)
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try `page.waitForTimeout(milliseconds)` and just give it a wait value for safety. It helped me is some cases to increase the waiting time where the test was going to timeout 5000ms because of the loading time.