# TimeoutError when clicking a button in Playwright

Tags: python, python-3.x, playwright

I got playwright._impl._errors.TimeoutError with the following code.

```
import asyncio
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def fb():
  async with async_playwright() as p:
    browser = await p.chromium.launch(args=["--disable-gpu", "--single-process"])
    page = await browser.new_page()

    await page.goto('https://www.facebook.com/zuck')
    s = "#mount_0_0_Y4 > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.x9f619.x1n2onr6.x1ja2u2z > div > div.x1uvtmcs.x4k7w5x.x1h91t0o.x1beo9mf.xaigb6o.x12ejxvf.x3igimt.xarpa2k.xedcshv.x1lytzrv.x1t2pt76.x7ja8zs.x1n2onr6.x1qrby5j.x1jfb8zj > div > div > div > div.x92rtbv.x10l6tqk.x1tk7jg1.x1vjfegm > div";
    
    await page.locator(s).get_by_role("button").click(); # TimeoutError
    
    await browser.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
  asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(fb())
```

How can I solve this issue? My environment is

- Docker base image : mcr.microsoft.com/playwright/python:v1.41.0-jammy
- Python 3.10.12
- playwright-1.41.2

The entire traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/function/dbgq.py", line 20, in <module>
    asyncio.new_event_loop().run_until_complete(fb())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/function/dbgq.py", line 15, in fb
    await page.locator(s).get_by_role("button").click(); # TimeoutError
  File "/function/playwright/async_api/_generated.py", line 15786, in click
    await self._impl_obj.click(
  File "/function/playwright/_impl/_locator.py", line 158, in click
    return await self._frame.click(self._selector, strict=True, **params)
  File "/function/playwright/_impl/_frame.py", line 494, in click
    await self._channel.send("click", locals_to_params(locals()))
  File "/function/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 63, in send
    return await self._connection.wrap_api_call(
  File "/function/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 495, in wrap_api_call
    return await cb()
  File "/function/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 101, in inner_send
    result = next(iter(done)).result()
playwright._impl._errors.TimeoutError: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
```

Comment: Did you try an untrusted click? `await page.locator(s).get_by_role("button").evaluate("el => el.click()");`. Your selector is ultra-rigid and prone to errors and breaking. There's likely a better selector. From the [docs](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath): "Long CSS or XPath chains below are an example of a bad practice that leads to unstable tests"

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be caused due to many reasons. You will need to do some debugging.

Case 1: page is not loaded completely. Depending on your tech you would need to have a page load wait. You can try a generic one if it works
[Wait for network idle after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74586859/wait-for-network-idle-after-click)

```
await page.locator(s).click()
await page.wait_for_load_state('networkidle')
```

Case 2 : the element is not loaded.
You will need to wait for the element to load before you click it
[TimeoutError when clicking a button in Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78055408/timeouterror-when-clicking-a-button-in-playwright)

```
await page.wait_for_selector(s, state="attached")
await page.locator(s).wait_for_element_state("visible")
await page.locator(s).click()
```

Case 3: the element loads but takes longer because of any reason. Increase your timeout. ( not recommended)

```
await page.locator(s).click(timeout=60000)
```

**Note:

Incorrect selector. Validate that the selector is correct.
your selector is hardcoded, which means if there is a big chance that change in that value during run time , will make your test fail.
https://playwright.dev/python/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath
please refer to the guide to enhance your selector**